# Display hyperlink in TextHover

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to write a custom eclipse plugin to extend the genericeditor with some features for a new language. The language has a multitude of built-in primitive functions (like + or -) and since most users won't know all of those primitives, I'm trying to implement an ITextHover, which displays information when hovering the mouse over one of those primitives. In particular, it should provide a link to the online language reference.

I am already able to display a text hover with some basic formatted html (see code below), but it won't display any hyperlinks.

**Any ideas what I have to do, so that links are displayed correctly, as well?**

```
public class HoverProvider implements ITextHover, ITextHoverExtension {


    @Override
    public IRegion getHoverRegion(ITextViewer tv, int off) {
        return new Region(off, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHoverInfo(ITextViewer tv, IRegion r) {
        try {
            DocumentHandler document = new DocumentHandler(tv.getDocument());
            char ch = document.getCharAt(r.getOffset());
            if (ch == 'D') {
                return "<h1>Information</h1> <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>";
            }
                return "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator() {
        return new IInformationControlCreator() {
            @Override
            public IInformationControl createInformationControl(Shell parent) {
                DefaultInformationControl dic = new DefaultInformationControl(parent,
                    EditorsUI.getTooltipAffordanceString());
                dic.setBackgroundColor(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), new RGB(254, 255, 204)));
                return dic;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass a `DefaultInformationControl.IInformationPresenter` to the `DefaultInformationControl` constructor. The default presenter is `org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.HTMLTextPresenter` which only does basic formatting.

Comment: I found that in the documentation, as well. However, do I need to write my own HTMLTextPresenter as the HTMLTextPresenter is in the internal package? The internal package is not supposed to be subclassed, is it?

Comment: That is correct, using internal packages is against the rules. You can choose to ignore the rules, but internal code can change at any time. You could copy all or part of the source code as long as you comply with the Eclipse Public License (which is pretty permissive).

Comment: Meaning the internal `BrowserInformationControl` , until some version of it is made API https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=218482 .

Comment: `org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.BrowserInformationControl` is used by things like Eclipse JDT for this instead of DefaultInformationControl, but again it is internal.

Comment: @user3617992 You can also use [Eclipse TM4E](https://github.com/eclipse/tm4e) to add HTML and other syntax highlighting to the generic text editor.